# Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server"

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, next.js13

I fetch this error when using Tremor's Chart Component in Next.js.
I can't understand the error I found some solutions and tried to solve this but still, I can't find the proper solution for this.

Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
<... className="mt-6" data={[...]} category=... index=... valueFormatter={function} colors=...>

This is an Error Message.

This is my code...

```
"use server";

import { Card, Title, DonutChart } from "@tremor/react";

const cities = [
  {
    name: "New York",
    sales: 9800,
  },
  {
    name: "London",
    sales: 4567,
  },
  {
    name: "Hong Kong",
    sales: 3908,
  },
  {
    name: "San Francisco",
    sales: 2400,
  },
  {
    name: "Singapore",
    sales: 1908,
  },
  {
    name: "Zurich",
    sales: 1398,
  },
];

// Mark the valueFormatter function as "use server"
// @ts-ignore
const valueFormatter = (number) =>
  `$ ${Intl.NumberFormat("us").format(number).toString()}`;

async function DonutChartComponent() {
  return (
    <Card className="max-w-lg">
      <Title>Sales</Title>
      <DonutChart
        className="mt-6"
        data={cities}
        category="sales"
        index="name"
        valueFormatter={valueFormatter}
        colors={["slate", "violet", "indigo", "rose", "cyan", "amber"]}
      />
    </Card>
  );
}

export default DonutChartComponent;
```

I added "use server" and // @ts-ignore comment which I found as a solution but still, I fetching a problem.

Comment: you need to change the component into client component.

"use client";

import { Card, Title, DonutChart } from "@tremor/react";

bla bla bla...

Comment: and don;t forget to restart your nextjs process in terminal